# How do I have the contents of a cell appear into the message of a msgbox

Tags: excel, cell, msgbox, vba

I'm trying to develop a `MsgBox` which displays a question in the `MsgBox` fed from a cell reference.

So in the example below the Msg "Please Enter The Number Of Hectares", I want to be picked up from say `Worksheet1 cell A1`.

```
Sub ComplainceQuestion()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim num As Double
    Dim Save
    num = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please Enter The Number Of Hectares", Type:=1)
        MsgBox Format(num * 2.47105, "#,##0.00") & " Is the Number Of Acre's."
        Save = MsgBox("Do you want to paste the result in a cell?", vbYesNo)
        If Save = vbYes Then
            Cell = Application.InputBox("Type In The Cell Reference, for example 'G64'")
            Range(Cell).Value = num * 2.471054
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code num is assigned the value of the user's input. To assign it the value of a cell, such as A1, just change the line num = Application.Inputbox... to num = Range("A1").value. Modified code:

```
Sub ComplainceQuestion()
On Error Resume Next
Dim num As Double
Dim Save
    num = Range("A1").Value
    MsgBox Format(num * 2.47105, "#,##0.00") & " Is the Number Of Acre's."
    Save = MsgBox("Do you want to paste the result in a cell?", vbYesNo)
    If Save = vbYes Then
        Cell = Application.InputBox("Type In The Cell Reference, for example 'G64'")
        Range(Cell).Value = num * 2.471054
    End If
    End Sub
```

Edit: change that before mentioned line to 
num = Application.InputBox(prompt:=Range("A1").Value, Type:=1)

Comment: I still want to show the input box, with a question. I want the input box message to be pulled from a cell, not a value for the calculation. Thanks